# Jython scripts doesn't work when executing in ODI

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have an ODI job with a procedure that have 3 Tasks. These tasks are coded in Jython technology. When I execute these scripts using Jython standalone in my PC are working fine, but when I run them from the ODI menu these doesn't make nothing.

The execution is marked as OK and I don't see any error logs in any window.

I checked that code works in jython standalone. Tried with paths using "/", using "\", my folder (Using windows in development mode) has all permissions available.

```
FILE_NAME =   "FILES-100-*-000001.csv"
NAS_FOLDER =  "/apps/dataflow/src/" 
WORK_FOLDER = "/apps/dataflow/target/"

#Extraemos prefijo y sufijo del fichero a procesar
splitted_value = FILE_NAME.split("*")
prefix = splitted_value[0]
suffix = splitted_value[1]

#Obtenemos listado de ficheros de la ruta del NAS y movemos los que cumplan condiciones al directorio WORK
files = os.listdir(NAS_FOLDER)
for file in files:
  if file.find(prefix) >= 0 and file.find(suffix) > 0:
    print "Fichero origen: " + NAS_FOLDER+file + " | Fichero destino: " + WORK_FOLDER+file
    try: 
      os.rename(NAS_FOLDER+file, WORK_FOLDER+file)
    except: 
      print("No se ha podido mover el fichero: " + NAS_FOLDER+file)
```

I expect the files moved succesfully. (These with the correct name and not moved before). I expect see any logs or error info too.

Thanks in advance.